# Can you start with no hair or beard?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Yesterday I started a new campaign (Primitive Plus, solo, PS4) and my character began with full hair and beard. Is there any way to **start** hairless and beardless? I would like to see it growing over time. I know you can (around level 15) craft scissors and cut it off, but I would like to know if I can start that way (which was supposed to be the default, according to some places I read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've figured it out. Apparently, you start with no hair or beard only in "classic" mode. If you play in Primitive Plus you start with full beard and long hair.

Answer (score 0):

If you start from scratch completely, you'll start no beard, etc. If you have a profile already there, you seem to spawn with a beard.

Comment: But I started from scratch. I even deleted my old save. It didn't work.